# Can someone help me, i cant find the error in my code of linked list

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista {
  int val;
  struct lista *next;
} lista;

void print(lista *head){
  printf("List:");
  while(head != NULL){
    printf("%d; ", head->val);
    head = head->next;}
}

void insert(lista  *p,int v){    
  lista *novo;
  if(p == NULL){
    novo = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->val = v;
    novo->next = NULL;
    p = novo;}
  else{
    novo =malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->val = v;
    novo->next = NULL;
    p->next = novo;
  }
}

int main()
{
  lista *head=NULL;
  int v;
  printf("Write the values u want to put in your list.(write 0 to exit)\n");
  while (v != 0){
    scanf("%d",&v);
    insert(head,v);}
  print(head);
}
```

Comment: There will be an error message in the output log if an error occurred, look there.

Comment: The problem is that i can't print the list. I don't think it's saving the values.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You declared int v;   I think you need to set v = 1; or non-zero integer to enter the while loop.  Does your code enter the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the reference of head pointer to edit it at function insert.
Maybe like: insert(&head,v) and function insert change to

```
void insert(lista  **p,int v){
  lista *novo;
  if(*p == NULL){
    novo = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->val = v;
    novo->next = NULL;
    *p = novo;}
  else{
    lista *head = *p;
    while(head->next != NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }
    novo =malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->val = v;
    novo->next = NULL;
    head->next = novo;
  }
}
```

it maybe work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program which can explain the code which Binh Ngyuyen provided:

```
void
set_sp1( int **x )  //line #3
{
  int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));  //line #4

  *i = 10000;   //line #5

  *x = i;  //line #6
}

int
main(void)
{
    int *pi1 = NULL;  //line #1

    set_sp1( &pi1 );  //line #2
    printf( "%d\n", *pi1); //line #7

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the explanation:

line #1

pi1 is a pointer to integer which is initialized to NULL.
What does it mean by this  statement?
Lets say pi1 variable occupies in memory address of 0XFFFF.
The value of pi1 is currently a NULL value.

Since, it is a pointer to an integer, pi1 eventually needs to have a value which  is a memory address of an integer.

```
 pi1
 ------------
 |  NULL    |
 ------------
 0XFFFF
```

line #2

The parameter is sending the address of pi1.
So. in this example, it is like set_sp1( 0XFFFF );

line #3

Upon the receipt of this parameter, the type becomes a double pointer to int since address of a single pointer was sent. 
The value of x is 0XFFFF.

```
       x
       ------------
       | 0XFFFF   |
       ------------
```

line #4

The variable i is a pointer to an integer.
i allocates a memory enough for an integer.
Lets say memory address of i resides at 0XAAAA.
The memory allocated address is 0XBBBB.
The value of i is 0XBBBB. 
Here is an important thing to remember.
The variable i is a local variable. So it will reside in stack memory.
At the termination of this function, the stack memory supposed to be wiped out.
However, 0XBBBB is in heap memory. So it will not be wiped out at the conclusion of the function.

```
            i                           a memory for int 
            ------------               ------------
            |  0XBBBB  |               |          |
            ------------               ------------
            0XAAAA                     0XBBBB
```

line #5
This line dereferences 0XBBBB in order to store a value of 10000 in the address 0XBBBB.

```
        --------
        |10000 |
        --------
        0XBBBB
```

line #6
Now, the finale, *(0XFFFF) = 0XBBBB.
The value at 0XFFFF was NULL.
But now it has 0XBBBB.

```
 ------------
 |  0XBBBB  |
 ------------
 0XFFFF
```

Once again, the value stored at 0XBBBB is 10000.

line #7
Now the value of pi1 no longer a NULL, it have a memory address of an int.
This is same as *(0XBBBB) which is dereferencing the value at this memory address which has a value of 10000.

Once again, thanks Bing Nguyen for the solution.
Hope this explanation gives a little better understanding.